# Django Stripe CheckoutSession page GET

Tags: javascript, python, django, stripe-payments

I am trying to use GET method on 127.0.0.1:8000/buy/1/ from 127.0.0.1:8000/item/1/, to get [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz2S4.png), just like if i simply go to "buy" page. But the button doesnt work for some reason. [But you can see /buy/1/ on a button in F12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaCBQ.png). Why?
Much thanks in advance.

Views

```
class ProductLandingPageView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'items/items.html'
    context_object_name = 'item'


class CreateCheckoutSessionView(View): 
    
    def get(self, request, pk):
        item_id = self.kwargs["pk"]
        item = Item.objects.get(id=item_id)

        checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            success_url="https://morungexpress.com/uploads/2022/01/36931750_1642339369_cc2dfdf7494bfa9436aac0d4a882a653.jpg",
            cancel_url="https://englishlib.org/dictionary/img/wlibrary/c/5ffdb27d24e086.50388072.jpg",
            mode="payment",
            line_items=[
                {
                    'price_data': {
                        'currency': 'usd',
                        'unit_amount': item.price,
                        'product_data': {
                            'name': item.name
                        },
                    },
                    "quantity": 1,
                }
            ]
            )
        return JsonResponse({
            'id': checkout_session.id
        })
```

URLS

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('item/<int:pk>/', ProductLandingPageView.as_view(), name='item'),
    path('buy/<int:pk>/', CreateCheckoutSessionView.as_view(), name='buy')
]
```

HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Buy {{ item.name }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <h1>{{ item.name }}</h1>
        <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
        <p>{{ item.price }}</p>
    <button id="buy-button">Buy</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_a9nwZVa5O7b0xz3lxl318KSU00x1L9ZWsF');
      var buyButton = document.getElementById(buy-button');
      buyButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        fetch("{% url 'buy' item.id %}", {
          method: 'GET'})
        .then(response => return response.json())
        .then(session => stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id }))
      });
    </script>

  </body>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few errors in the frontend code:

- `Stripe` is not defined. Make sure you include it as [explained here](https://stripe.com/docs/js/including)
- `document.getElementById(buy-button')` should be `document.getElementById('buy-button')` (a `'` is missing)
- `.then(response => return response.json())` should be `.then(response => response.json())` (no `return` keyword)

If that still doesn't fix the issue, please add some logs to your code and make sure to include the exact error messages you see.

Answer (score -1):

There is a typo error in your variable declaration

```
var buyButton = document.getElementById(buy-button');
```

It's meant to be:

```
var buyButton = document.getElementById('.buy-button');
```

Comment: Thanks! But it didnt fix the main problem :(

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).